# Tinymce + MCImageManager append random string to uploaded file name

Tags: tinymce, mcimagemanager

Tinymce + MCImageManager append random string to uploaded file name. I tried to find answer in google and offical documantion, but i can't found relevant things.

So anybody can tell me how can i config my MCimageManager. ( I would not want modify core files but if not have any way to do that ... )

Hi
Attila

Comment: +1 You should ask your question here: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/